# Firestore rules to allow read a field if below certain value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

a doc with multiple fields but I want a condition to one field where only if it is below a certain value it can be read.. the rest of the fields can be read at any time.... so at the user end it will either return the value or null for that conditioned field

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha, so for this, just write an if statement that checks each input field to see if it meets your conditions.

```
    if(input1.value == "juice" && input2.value != "apple"){
       docRef
            .collection("posts")
            .doc()
            .collection("burgers")
            .add({
            input1: input1,
            input2: input2
    })
    }else{
 console.log("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Security rules control access to documents, not specific fields.
As a consequence, if you want certain fields to be always accessible, while controlling access to other fields, you have two possibilities:
1- put the accessible fields in a document, and the private fields in an other document, then write the security rules for the private document
2- restrict direct access to the document and access it through a Cloud Function where you can hide or show certain fields.

If you choose to go with separate documents, here is the security rule that will prevent access to a document if the field *foo* is below 123:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /students/{studentId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.foo >= 123;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```